# How to stop ViewController in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

my `ViewController` is still sending an array update, even if I'm in another View, what can I do? Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class ViewController: UIViewController {
var audioVibe : AudioVibes!
var superpowered:Superpowered!
var displayLink:CADisplayLink!
var layers:[CALayer]!
var magnitudeArray : [UInt16] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Setup 8 layers for frequency bars.
    let color:CGColorRef = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0.6, blue: 0.8, alpha: 1).CGColor
    layers = [CALayer(), CALayer(), CALayer(), CALayer(), CALayer(), CALayer(), CALayer(), CALayer()]
    for n in 0...7 {
        layers[n].backgroundColor = color
        layers[n].frame = CGRectZero
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(layers[n])
    }

    superpowered = Superpowered()

    // A display link calls us on every frame (60 fps).
    displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.onDisplayLink))
    displayLink.frameInterval = 1
    displayLink.addToRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
}

// Gets triggered when you leave the ViewController.
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    superpowered.togglePlayback();
    superpowered.moritz();
    //delete(superpowered);
}

func onDisplayLink() {
    // Get the frequency values.
    let magnitudes = UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>.alloc(8)
    superpowered.getMagnitudes(magnitudes)

    // Wrapping the UI changes in a CATransaction block like this prevents animation/smoothing.
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(0)
    CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)

    // Set the dimension of every frequency bar.
    let originY:CGFloat = self.view.frame.size.height - 20
    let width:CGFloat = (self.view.frame.size.width - 47) / 5
    var frame:CGRect = CGRectMake(20, 0, width, 0)
    for n in 0...4 {
        frame.size.height = CGFloat(magnitudes[n]) * 2000
        frame.origin.y = originY - frame.size.height
        layers[n].frame = frame
        frame.origin.x += width + 1
    }

    // Set the magnitudes in the array.
    for n in 0...6 {
        magnitudeArray[n] = UInt16(magnitudes[n] * 32768)
    }

    // Update the array in the audioVibe class to trigger the sending command.
    audioVibe.magnitudeArray = magnitudeArray

    CATransaction.commit()

    // Dealloc the magnitudes.
    magnitudes.dealloc(8)
}

}
```

I want him to stop doing things like `audioVibe.magnitudeArray = magnitudeArray` while I'm not in his view, what can I do?

Thanks!

Comment: what `viewWill...` and `viewDid...` functions have you thought about using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your viewDidLoad method you're creating a CADisplayLink and adding it to the run loop.

If you don't do anything, that display link will stay active when you push another view controller on top of it.

You should move the code that creates the display link and adds it to the run loop to your viewWillAppear method.

Then you need to add code in viewWillDisappear that removes the display link from the run loop, invalidates it, and nils it out.

That way, you'll start your display link code when the view appears, and stop it when the view disappears.

Comment: How do I remove it from the runloop?

Comment: Take a look at the Xcode docs on CADisplayLink. The answer will be **painfully** obvious.

Comment: Or, as cjrieck points out, you can leave the display link in place and just pause it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you display link isn't getting paused when you transition to different views.

You could pause your display link when transitioning away from this view and resume it when coming back to this view using the `paused` property on `CADisplayLink`. You would pause it in `viewWillDisappear` and resume in `viewWillAppear`.